# В таблицу с полем типа [image] вставить jpg-картинку?

Tags: sql, sql-server

для этого используя SQL QUERY Analyzer и БД Sql Server 2000

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через оболочку SQL Query Analyzer (SQL Server 2000) не получилось реализовать запросом вставку в таблицу с полем "image" картинок через хранимую процедуру потому что остается вопрос чем открыть содержимое файла(например, утилите **BCP** права нужны)...а хотелось бы попроще. Используя скрипт VBS решил так:

```vb
' === Script Information Header === 
' Script Name: load.vbs
' Description: Load image in table, database..
' === Initialization Block ===  
Dim cn,rs
Const adTypeBinary = 1

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

'Create Stream object
Dim BinaryStream
Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
cn.ConnectionString = "File Name=you_connect.udl" 

cn.Open
rs.Open "you_table", cn, 1, 2
' where field 'img' type 'image'

' read file jpg(binary data):
BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
BinaryStream.Open
BinaryStream.LoadFromFile "C:\you_img.jpg"
bytesBLOB = BinaryStream.Read

rs.addnew
'...
rs.fields("img").AppendChunk bytesBLOB
rs.Update
BinaryStream.Close

MsgBox("Insert image!") 

' close connection db 
cn.Close 
Set cn = Nothing 
' --
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ImageField) 
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\picture.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T
```

это для более современных SQL-серверов, а в вашем случае надо writetext использовать, что-то вроде этого:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
    ImageField IMAGE NULL
)
GO

-- must insert a dummy value into the image column for TEXTPTR 
DECLARE @RowId INT
INSERT Table1 (ImageField) VALUES (0xFFFFFFFF)
SELECT @RowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
-- get a pointer value
DECLARE @Ptr varbinary(16)
SELECT @Ptr = TEXTPTR(ImageField)
FROM Table1
WHERE Id = @RowId
-- write the image
WRITETEXT Table1.ImageField @Ptr 'c:\picture.jpg'
```

передать содержимое картинки можно через ХП

```
create procedure writeImage
@content image
as
    DECLARE @RowId INT
    INSERT Table1 (ImageField) VALUES (0xFFFFFFFF)
    SELECT @RowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    -- get a pointer value
    DECLARE @Ptr varbinary(16)
    SELECT @Ptr = TEXTPTR(ImageField)
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Id = @RowId
    -- write the image
    WRITETEXT Table1.ImageField @Ptr @content
GO
```

есть ещё вариант с использованием утилиты **BCP** (параметр **IN**), но у вас должны быть права **xp_cmdshell**

Comment: почти оно, но немного не то: в колонке типа image будет такое 'c:\picture.jpg'...но не байты картинки...именно туда нужно запихнуть содержимое картинки. если была бы функция ReadFromFile вместо WRITETEXT или типа того

Answer (score 0):

Вот по этой ссылке есть примеры для SQL Server 2000: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175795.aspx.

Comment: Ссылки имею свойство протухать. Включите основную информацию по ссылке в сам ответ.